# Shiny: Is it possible to make a vertical slider?

Tags: r, slider, shiny

Is there any possibility to make a vertical slider in Shiny? I would basically want a plot, a vertical slider at its left, and a normal horizontal slider below it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Now it is very easy with this `noUiSliderInput()`  from the [shinyWidgets](https://rdrr.io/github/dreamRs/shinyWidgets/man/noUiSliderInput.html) package.

Example:

```
if (interactive()) {

### examples ----

# see ?demoNoUiSlider
demoNoUiSlider("more")


###  basic usage ----

library( shiny )
library( shinyWidgets )


ui <- fluidPage(

  tags$br(),

  noUiSliderInput(
    inputId = "noui1",
    min = 0, max = 100,
    value = 20
  ),
  verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "res1"),

  tags$br(),

  noUiSliderInput(
    inputId = "noui2", label = "Slider vertical:",
    min = 0, max = 1000, step = 50,
    value = c(100, 400), margin = 100,
    orientation = "vertical",
    width = "100px", height = "300px"
  ),
  verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "res2")

)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$res1 <- renderPrint(input$noui1)
  output$res2 <- renderPrint(input$noui2)

}

shinyApp(ui, server)

}
```

Comment: Note that placed within a ``tabPanel``, they do not align well, but if embedded within ``div(style="display:inline-block", ... )`` they all show nicely.

Answer (score 5):

There are ways to do it manually. You would need to create a custom `js`.

Here is a crazy shinny app where everything rotates

```
    #Libs
    require(c('shiny'))
    js<-"$(function() {
        var $elie = $('div');
        rotate(25);
        function rotate(degree) {        
            $elie.css({ WebkitTransform: 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)'});  
            $elie.css({ '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)'});
            timer = setTimeout(function() {
                rotate(++degree);
            },100);
        }
    });"


    renderInputs <- function(prefix) {
      wellPanel(
        fluidRow(
          column(3,
                 sliderInput(paste0(prefix, "_", "n_obs"), "View a specific date", min = as.Date('1980-05-15'), max = Sys.Date(), value = as.Date('2000-01-01'),
                 #sliderInput("date_range", "Choose Date Range:", min = as.Date("2016-02-01"), max = Sys.Date(), value = c(as.Date("2016-02-25"), Sys.Date())
                 ),
                 verbatimTextOutput("info")
          ),
          column(9,
                 plotOutput("plot1",
                            click = "plot_click",
                            dblclick = "plot_dblclick",
                            hover = "plot_hover",
                            brush = "plot_brush")
          )
        )
      )
    }

    ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(theme="simplex.min.css",
                            tags$style(type="text/css",
                                       "label {font-size: 12px;}",
                                       ".recalculating {opacity: 1.0;}"
                            ),
                            tags$head(
                              tags$style(HTML("
                                              @import url('//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster|Cabin:400,700');

                                              h1 {
                                              font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
                                              font-weight: 500;
                                              line-height: 1.1;
                                              color: #48ca3b;
                                              }

                                              ")),
                              tags$script(HTML(js))
                              ),

                            # Application title
                            tags$h2("Google!!!"),
                            p("An adaptation of the",
                              tags$a(href="https://google.com", "Google"),
                              "from",
                              tags$a(href="https://duckduckgo.com/", "DuckDuckGo"),
                              "to get the best possible results without selling yourself"),
                            hr(),

                            fluidRow(
                              column(6, tags$h3("Scenario A")),
                              column(6, tags$h3("Scenario B"))
                            ),
                            fluidRow(
                              column(12, renderInputs("a"))
                            ),
                            fluidRow(
                              column(6,
                                     plotOutput("a_distPlot", height = "600px")
                              ),
                              column(6,
                                     plotOutput("b_distPlot", height = "600px")
                              )
                            )
                              )
                  )


    server <- function(input, output) {
      output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
        plot(mtcars$wt, mtcars$mpg)
      })

      output$info <- renderText({
        xy_str <- function(e) {
          if(is.null(e)) return("NULL\n")
          paste0("x=", round(e$x, 1), " y=", round(e$y, 1), "\n")
        }
        xy_range_str <- function(e) {
          if(is.null(e)) return("NULL\n")
          paste0("xmin=", round(e$xmin, 1), " xmax=", round(e$xmax, 1), 
                 " ymin=", round(e$ymin, 1), " ymax=", round(e$ymax, 1))
        }

        paste0(
          "click: ", xy_str(input$plot_click),
          "dblclick: ", xy_str(input$plot_dblclick),
          "hover: ", xy_str(input$plot_hover),
          "brush: ", xy_range_str(input$plot_brush)
        )
      })
    }

    shinyApp(ui, server)


    ################################
```

If you want it to work rotate only one element you need to modify the `js` like this:

```
    js<-"$(function() {
      var $elie = $(document.getElementsByClassName('form-group shiny-input-container'));
    rotate(270);
    function rotate(degree) {        
        $elie.css({ WebkitTransform: 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)'});  
        $elie.css({ '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)'});
    }
});"
```

It still needs a bit of work to fix the functionality like the sliding and the padding of the div and adding a custom id on all the elements you wish to rotate:thus making sure you wont apply the js on element you do not want to and get the mess from the first example, but it should be a good starting point.

Comment: thankyou! I can see this could be a start. The first one is indeed crazy! The 2nd one with just the slider rotated looks good but, as you suggest the slider still detects left-right mouse movement to move the slider up-down. Is that fixable ?

Comment: Yes. My best guess is to over write the functions from the js correlated to this. Another way is to simply not use the shiny slider and add one of your own using some code from other sources like here: https://jqueryui.com/slider/#multiple-vertical

Comment: did any of you find a solution for the mouse dragging direction? I was building the same thing, a rotated slider, and indeed found out while the slider is easy to rotate, the mouse action remains horizontal

Comment: Have not done any work on this, but something that might work is to put this whole thing in a div container and rotate the container? On the other hand it is also possible that this approach is just too much work and there might be another implementation? I have not used it so this is now just guess word.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for it too, and I think it is not implemented. In the shiny discussion group there is a similar question from november 2014, and it`s still open.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/shiny-discuss/vertical$20slider

Searching the [official gallery](http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/) and the web, I couldn`t find any example of it. All sliders are horizontals. Always.

Comment: This is not an answer.