# Reactiveness in custom widgets

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

I need to have a vertical slider input. Since this is not possible with the built-in sliderInput function, I opted to implement it myself.
According to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28436842/shiny-is-it-possible-to-make-a-vertical-slider) it is either possible to (I) rotate the sliderInput widget using CSS or (II) use a common slider and implement the capability to interact with Shiny.
I decided to go for option (II) because (I) did not work out the way I wanted.

I followed [this article](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/building-inputs.html) in order to implement a custom verticalSlider function

```
verticalSlider <- function(inputId, min, max, value) {
  tagList(
    singleton(tags$head(tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/9.8.1/css/bootstrap-slider.min.css"))),
    singleton(tags$head(tags$script(src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/9.8.1/bootstrap-slider.min.js"))),

    singleton(tags$head(tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href = "css/verticalSlider.css"))),
    singleton(tags$head(tags$script(src = "js/verticalSlider.js"))),

    tags$input(id = inputId,
               class = "verticalSlider",
               type = "text",
               value = "",
               `data-slider-min` = as.character(min),
               `data-slider-max` = as.character(max),
               `data-slider-step` = as.character(1),
               `data-slider-value` = as.character(min),
               `data-slider-orientation` = "vertical"
    )
  )
}
```

I implemented the input binding and initialized the slider in "js/verticalSlider.js".

```
$(function() {
  $('.verticalSlider').each(function() {
      $(this).slider({
        reversed : true,
        handle : 'square',
        change: function(event, ui){}
     });
    });
});

var verticalSliderBinding = new Shiny.InputBinding();
  $.extend(verticalSliderBinding, {
    find: function(scope) {
      return $(scope).find(".verticalSlider");
  },
  getValue: function(el) {
    return $(el).value;
  },
  setValue: function(el, val) {
    $(el).value = val;
  },
  subscribe: function(el, callback) {
    $(el).on("change.verticalSliderBinding", function(e) {
      callback();
    });
  },
  unsubscribe: function(el) {
    $(el).off(".verticalSliderBinding");
  },
  getRatePolicy: function() {
            return {
            policy: 'debounce',
            delay: 150
            };
  }
});

Shiny.inputBindings.register(verticalSliderBinding, "shiny.verticalSlider");
```

So far so good. The subscribe function is called everytime I move the slider's knob.

**Moving the handle has no effect when the slider's value is bound to a textOutput however.**
Shiny's "reactiveness" does not seem to work for my custom component. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi according to bootstrap-slider [readme](https://github.com/seiyria/bootstrap-slider), you should rewrite `getValue` and `setValue` methods in your bindings :

```
getValue: function(el) {
  return $(el).slider('getValue');
},
setValue: function(el, val) {
  $(el).slider('setValue', val);
}
```

I think `setValue` is only used if you define an update method.

Comment: Wow, thanks! I certainly did not expect the error there. Works as expected now!